# Who owns the content posted on .wordpress.com blogs?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

If I sign up for a Wordpress blog that is hosted for free by Wordpress [here](http://wordpress.com/), who will own the content I post, and how much storage will I have? I know I could ask their customer support, but I don't trust companies (their lawyers specifically).

Comment: The terms of service for WordPress.com are here: http://en.wordpress.com/tos/

Comment: Voting to close. This has nothing to do with the administration of a WordPress site. Your paranoia doesn't make this the right place for this question.

Comment: You trust random people on the Internet? :)

Comment: @John: Whether we allow WP.com questions [was discussed on meta](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52/are-wordpress-com-questions-welcome) - [multiple times](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/330/should-we-drop-wordpress-com-questions-from-the-site) - and the outcome is not very clear. Because this question got a quick answer, I don't think we have to close it.

Comment: @John P Bloch While the form of the question is little paranoid indeed, I see nothing wrong or off-topic about question itself. :) Fine by me.

Comment: @Jan I didn't vote to close because it was a WP.com question; I voted to close because I think it's just plain off topic. It has less to do with WordPress, the open source web publishing platform, than it does with Automattic, the company that maintains an instance of WordPress at WP.com. The speed of the answer should be immaterial.

Comment: @Rarst It's not that I think it's a bad question; it's that I think it's a question that doesn't belong here, since it's a question about Automattic's policies, not about WordPress.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [TOS](http://en.wordpress.com/tos/):

> By submitting Content to Automattic for inclusion on your Website, you grant Automattic a world-wide, royalty-free, and non-exclusive license to reproduce, modify, adapt and publish the Content solely for the purpose of displaying, distributing and promoting your blog. If you delete Content, Automattic will use reasonable efforts to remove it from the Website, but you acknowledge that caching or references to the Content may not be made immediately unavailable.

It means that you own it but they have full rights.

Answer (score 1):

For storage: you can upload up to [3 gigabytes of attachments for free](http://en.support.wordpress.com/space-upgrade/), and can pay for upgrades after that. I think post content has no limit (and it would be very hard to reach 3 gigabytes with post content alone).